# What is the feasible region of first-order polynomials $x$, $y$ with unknown coefficients in $[-1, 1]$?

Tags: inequality, linear-programming, convex-hulls, upper-lower-bounds

I need the feasible region of polynomials:

$$x = x_0 + x_1 e_1 + \cdots + x_n e_n$$

$$y = y_0 + y_1 e_1 + \cdots + y_n e_n$$

with $e_i \in [-1, 1]$, for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.

We are given $x_0, x_1, ..., x_n$ and $y_0, y_1, ..., y_n$, but all $e_i$ are unknown, and vary independently (think of them as noise symbols for each term - e.g. rounding errors). I want to know what $x$ and $y$ can equal if we independently perturb all $e_i$ symbols between $−1$ and $1$. Note that, for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, $x_i e_i$ and $y_i e_i$ terms are correlated, because they both share the $e_i$ noise symbol. The context is [affine arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_arithmetic), if that helps at all.

Is this possible? I looked at a seemingly related method by the name of linear programming, but I cannot figure out how to formulate the problem properly when there are many bounded variables, as in the above equations.

I have a rather brute-force MATLAB algorithm that computes the convex hull of the equations, with all permutations of the bounded $e$ coefficients set to $-1$ and $1$, but it is useless when $n$ is large.

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the 'feasible region of polynomials'? Polynomials are defined everywhere.

Comment: OK, maybe I'm using the wrong terminology. What I mean is I want to know the set of all possible tuples $(x, y)$, on the LHS of the above equations, with the constraint that all $e_1, ..., e_n$ must be bounded by $[-1, 1]$. So in this particular case, the polynomials cannot be defined everywhere, due to the bounded $e_i$.

Comment: Excuse me, I mean they *are* defined everywhere, of course, but the set of all possible tuples $(x, y)$ form a bounded region in the shape of a convex hull. I hope that is clearer.

Comment: So $x$ can only lie in $[(x_0 - \sum^n_{i=1} |x_i|), (x_0 + \sum^n_{i=1} |x_i|)]$.

Comment: It is still not clear to me what you are trying to do. Are you asking to compute $\{A y\}_{\|y\|_\infty \le 1}$ where $Ay = \binom{x_0}{y_0} + \binom{x_1 \cdots x_n}{y_1\cdots y_n} y$?

Comment: We are given $x_0, x_1, ..., x_n$ and $y_0, y_1, ..., y_n$, but all $e_i$ are unknown, and vary independently (think of them as noise symbols for each term - e.g. rounding errors). I want to know what $x$ and $y$ can equal if we independently perturb all $e_i$ symbols between $-1$ and $1$. Note that, for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, $x_i e_i$ and $y_i e_i$ terms are correlated, because they both share the $e_i$ noise symbol. The context is "affine arithmetic", if that helps at all.

Comment: I wrote a more algorithmic description (MATLAB), which could potentially be easier to understand, on Stack Overflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950725/matlab-efficient-way-to-find-the-feasible-region-of-first-order-polynomials-x

Comment: Question is revised.

Comment: How are you expecting the 'feasible region' to be described?

Comment: Preferably as the set of all corner points of the reachable region. Thanks for your perseverance!

Comment: If not, the linear equations describing the edges is also fine.

Comment: Well, the convex hull will be $\operatorname{co} \{ \sum_{k \ge 1} \sigma_k \binom{x_k}{y_k} | \sigma_k \in \{\pm 1\}\} + \{ \binom{x_0}{y_0} \}$, but you already know that. I don't see how to simplify this without additional constraints.